# 24 hour to 12 hour converter

Tags: java, clock

I see a lot of people new to Java asking for this one, but not in the way that I am.  I saw a lot of good information on how to do this conversion and I like many of the ideas but none of them directly represent the problem I am having.

I am asking the user for three Ints representing the time currently, the problem is that when they enter 00 for the hour it repeats a double zero instead of 12.  I can't quite figure out how to tell it that.  Would I use a if (hour == 00) hour = 12

how do I phrase that correctly? also, I need it to say hour with a 0 in front of the time for 1- 9 for 09:15:15AM
instead of 9:15:15 AM  My instructor said to use print F but that would bust my current code.  Is this the wrong way to do this?

Help is appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ps5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a time value in the following format: HH MM SS");
        int hour = keyboard.nextInt();
        int minute = keyboard.nextInt();
        int second = keyboard.nextInt();
        int trueHour = hour.

  if (hour < 23 && hour >= 0)
       if (hour > 11)
        {
            if (hour == 12) hour = 24;
            System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02dPM\n", (hour - 12), minute, second);
        }
        else
        {
            if (hour == 00) hour = 12;
            System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02dAM\n", hour , minute, second);
        }
    else
            System.out.print("Hour must be between 0 and 23 inclusive.");

    }
}
```

Comment: "Would I use a if (hour == 00) hour = 12" - Well, why not?

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed that if the hour is equal to 12, in your current code, it thinks that is AM.  But if the 24 hour time is 12:30:00, that's supposed to be PM, not AM.

Comment: Why would 0 mean 12? It's a 24-hour clock. 0 means 0. In a 24-hour clock, hours are 0-23. In a 12-hour clock, hours are 1-12, or more precisely 12,1-11.

Comment: Midnight represented in a 24-hour clock is 00.  That is what I meant.

Comment: I used 2 if statements to cleant his up The hypergrade didnt check for an 11 answer so this worked for the homework.  Its not correct but it worked lol.

Comment: if (hour == 12) hour = 24;
                System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02dPM\n", (hour - 12), minute, second);

Comment: if (hour < 23 && hour >= 0)
           if (hour > 11)
            {
                if (hour == 12) hour = 24;
                System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02dPM\n", (hour - 12), minute, second);
            }
            else
            {
                if (hour == 00) hour = 12;
                System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02dAM\n", hour , minute, second);
            }
        else

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing all the conversion stuff yourself why not use the java time api?

This uses [java.time.LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for the conversion and should be capable of replacing everything inside your if statment. You will still have to do your own input validation.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.of(hour,minute,second);
System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a")));
```

I sadly can not verify that this works at the moment since I am not at work but this should be a decent starting point.

Comment: I wish I had the knowledge of this. I am not that advanced yet lol

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close:

```
String ampm = "AM";
// You check hour but not minute or second
if (second >= 0 && second < 60 && minute >= 0 && minute < 60 && hour <= 23 && hour >= 0) {
    // Check PM
    if (hour >= 12) {
        // Only subtract when hour != 12
        if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
        }
        ampm = "PM";
    }
    else if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }
    // Instructor says use printf...
    System.out.printf("%d:%02d:%02d %s", hour, minute, second, ampm);
}
else {
    // Print an error....
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post with the code that worked for the homework. Its not right but it worked. I don't have enough knowledge yet to solve this one the right way.

Comment: awesome i didnt know i could use that -=

Comment: just putting text to this so I understand it right I am reading it this way.  if hour is greater then or equal to 12 execute true if hour greater then 12 hour subtracts 12 using -= string ampm is assigned PM.

Comment: @SeanGowing "If hour is >= 12 then it's PM. And if hour > 12 (but not 12) subtract 12".